# Java 8 : Get files from folder / subfolder

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming, stream

I have this folders inside the resources folder of a **SpringBoot** app.

```
resources/files/a.txt
resources/files/b/b1.txt
resources/files/b/b2.txt
resources/files/c/c1.txt
resources/files/c/c2.txt
```

I want to get all the txt file, so this is my code:

```
   ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
   Path configFilePath = Paths.get(classLoader.getResource("files").toURI());   

   List<Path> atrackFileNames = Files.list(configFilePath)
                .filter(s -> s.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                .map(Path::getFileName)
                .sorted()
                .collect(toList());
```

But I only get the file **a.txt**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
    Path configFilePath = FileSystems.getDefault()
            .getPath("C:\\Users\\sharmaat\\Desktop\\issue\\stores");

    List<Path> fileWithName = Files.walk(configFilePath)
            .filter(s -> s.toString().endsWith(".java"))
            .map(Path::getFileName).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (Path name : fileWithName) {
        // printing the name of file in every sub folder
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

`Files.list(path)` method returns only stream of files in directory. And the method listing is not recursive.
Instead of that you should use `Files.walk(path)`. This method walks through all file tree rooted at a given starting directory.
More about it:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-